# Subgroups of smallest possible index in a solvable group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

The following question appears in Isaacs' Finite Group Theory:

3B.15) (Berkovich) Let $G$ be solvable, and let $H<G$ be a proper subgroup having the smallest possible index in $G$. Show that $H\lhd G$.

If we assume that $G$ is a minimal counterexample, then it is possible to show that $H$ has trivial core in $G$, that $H$ is a complement of the Fitting subgroup of $G$, and that the Fitting subgroup is a unique minimal normal subgroup of $G$. But this mostly follows from the fact that $H$ must be a maximal subgroup of $G$, rather than using the fact that $H$ has smallest possible index. It also doesn't seem to lead to any contradiction.

I cannot find the solution. Problem 3B.12 from the same chapter is wrong, so there is the possibility that this question is wrong too. If it is wrong, are there any counterexamples?

Answer (score 6):

So, using the action of $G$ on the cosets of $H$, we can regard $G$ as a subgroup of $S_n$, where $H=G_\alpha$ is a point stabilizer and $n=|G:H|$. The minimal normal subgroup $N$ is regular and abelian, so $|N|=n$.

Since $H \ne 1$, there is a point $\beta$ with $H_\beta \ne H$. Then $|H:H_\beta|$ is the length of the orbit of $H$ on $\beta$, and hence is less than $n$, so $|G:NH_\beta| < n$, contradicting the minimality of $n$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I missed a point. Why $N$ must be regular ? (N may be contained in H)

Comment: We are assuming that $H$ is core-free in $G$, so we cannot have $N \le H$. But, since $H$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$,  $G$ is a primitive subgroup of $S_n$, and $N \lhd G$, so $N$ must be transitive. And, since (as a minimal normal subgroup) $N$ is elementary abelian, it must be regular.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @DerekHolt May I ask for reference for the attribution of the proposition to Berkovich? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As you can see from the question, this attribution comes from Exercise 3B.16 of Isaacs' book Finite Group Theory. I don't know of any other.

Answer (score 4):

Although all credits go to Derek Holt, here is a more elaborate proof using the theory developed in the preceding chapters of Isaacs' book.

*I.M. Isaacs - Finite Group Theory, Problem 3B.15*

(**Berkovich**) Let $G$ be a solvable group and $H$ a proper subgroup of smallest possible index. Then $H$ is a *normal* subgroup.

**Proof** (Any reference to a Theorem, Lemma, Corollary or Problem will be from the aforementioned book) Let us assume that $H$ is *not* normal. We will derive a contradiction by constructing a proper subgroup with smaller index than that of $H$.
 By induction on $|G|$ we can assume that core$_G(H)=1$ (see also Theorem 1.1). Note that $|H|$ is a non-normal maximal subgroup, and hence $H=N_G(H)$. Put index$[G:H]=n$. Let $N$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$. By Lemma 3.11, $N$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group (that is $N \cong C_p \times \cdots \times C_p$, $p$ prime).

Consider the subgroup $HN$. Since $H$ is maximal, we either have $H=HN$ or $G=HN$. The first case is impossible since this is equivalent to $N \subseteq H$, contradicting core$_G(H)=1$. So $G=HN$ and since $N$ is normal and abelian it follows that $H \cap N$ is normalized by both $H$ and $N$, which gives $H \cap N \lhd G$. Again, since core$_G(H)=1$, we get $H \cap N=1$.This implies that $|N|=$index$[G:H]=n$, a prime-power (and solves *en passant* Problem 3B.1)

Now let us have a look at the action of $H$ on $N$ by conjugation. Of course the orbit of $1 \in N$, $\mathcal{O}_1=\{1\}$ and this implies that all other orbits must have a length $\leq n-1$. We claim that if $g \in N-\{1\}$, then the length of its orbit $\mathcal{O}_g$ equals index$[H:H \cap H^g]$. By the Fundamental Counting Principle (Theorem 1.4) this is equivalent to showing that the stabilizer subgroup of $g$ equals $H \cap H^g$. Let $h \in H$ and suppose $g^h=h^{-1}gh=g$. Then $h=g^{-1}hg \in H^g$, whence $h \in H \cap H^g$. Conversely, assume that $h \in H \cap H^g$, say $h=g^{-1}kg$ for some $k \in H$. Then $hk^{-1}=g^{-1}(kgk^{-1})$. The left-hand side, $hk^{-1} \in H$, the right-hand side $\in N$, since $N$ is normal. But $H \cap N=1$, so $h=k$ and $h$ and $g$ commute. This proves the claim.

Now fix a $g \in N-\{1\}$ and put $K=(H \cap H^g)N$. We will show that $K$ is a proper subgroup of $G$ and that index $[G:K] \lt n$, finally contradicting the choice of $H$. Suppose $G=(H \cap H^g)N$. Note that $(H \cap H^g) \cap N=1$ and this gives by comparing indices, index$[H: H \cap H^g]=1$, so $H=H \cap H^g$, implying $H=H^g$. But then $g \in N_G(H) \cap N= H \cap N=1$, contradicting the choice of $g$. So $K$ is a proper subgroup.
Now using Corollary X.11, $|G|=|HN|=\frac{|H||N|}{|H \cap N|}=|H||N|$. Similarly, $|K|=|(H \cap H^g)N|=|H \cap H^g||N|$. This shows that index$[G:K]=$index$[H:H \cap H^g]=\#\mathcal{O}_g \lt n$. The proof is now complete.

**Corollary** Let $G$ be a solvable group and $H$ a proper subgroup of largest possible order. Then $H$ is a *normal* subgroup.

Comment: very neat solution

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Can we say that the orbit of $g\in N-\{1\}$ under the action of $G$ must be $\{g\}$ by the minimality of $|G:H|$, which implies $N\subseteq \mathbf{Z}(G)$? This would imply that both $N$ and $H$ are contained in the normalizer of $H$ in $G=NH$, so $H$ should be normal in $G$, contradicting our assumption.

Comment: @Absol yes I think you are right, each centralizer of a non-trivial element of $N$ must be equal to $G$. So $N$ would be central. Neat remark, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### More of the same, perhaps shorter.

Since the smallest possible index corresponds to the greatest possible order, $H$ is maximal.

Let $C=\text{core}_G(H)$. If $C\ne\langle1\rangle$, induction on $|G|$ implies that $H/C\triangleleft G/C$ because $|G/C:H/C|=|G:H|$ is the smallest possible index in $G/C$. Hence, $H\triangleleft G$ and we are done.

Now suppose, toward a contradiction, that $C=\langle1\rangle$. Take $N$ minimal normal in $G$. Then we have: (1) $N\cap H\triangleleft N$ because $N$ is (elementary) abelian, and (2) $N\cap H\triangleleft H$ because $N\triangleleft G$. In consequence, $N\cap H\triangleleft NH=G$. Thus, $N\cap H=1$ and $|N|=|G:H|$.

Consider the action of $H$ on $N$ by conjugation. By the fundamental counting principle,
$$
    |{\cal O}_y| = |H:H_y|\qquad (y\in N).
$$
Since ${\cal O}_1=\{1\}$ we deduce that $|{\cal O}_y|\le |N|-1$ because orbits are disjoint subsets of $N$. According to Problem 3B.12, there exists $K$ with $|G:K|=|H:H_y|$. Then,
$$
    |G:K| = |H:H_y| = |{\cal O}_y| \le |N|-1 = |G:H|-1,
$$
which, as anticipated, contradicts the hypothesis on $|G:H|$ when $y\ne1$.